# AppCompat giving error in style.xml

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-appcompat

I am using eclipse for one old existing android app. app was previously using actionBarSherlock, I switch to AppCompat this project.. added AppCompat support v7 project as library . so related to AppCompat Java imports are resolved , but in style.xml it is giving problem .. for eg.

```
  <style name="customActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/darkblue</item>
    <item name="background">@color/darkblue</item>
  </style>
```

here this parent name is not resolved.. please guide me on this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: add your `build.gradle` file's content, please

Comment: Im using eclipses so eclipse ADT is not suitable to use gradle.build .. let me correct if i am wrong

Comment: why you use Eclipse when it is deprecated and already not supported by Google

Comment: reason behind this is I love to work on android studio, but there was existing project developed in eclipse and then I generated gradle for android and import the project into android studio.. Previous project was using actionbarsherlock  I replace it with new library appCompat then I clean and rebuild in android studio .. working fine.. but while trying to run app in device , gradle is not stopping for many hours (more than 8 hours). so I tried same in eclipse. then I got problem mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

At first,clean your project and rebuild it. If doesn't work, remove your support v7 library and do first step again.